# Tikz arrows on loops not showing up

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am trying to draw a diagram with arrows between boxes. Most of them show up fine, but an arrow head on a loop from a node to itself does not.

I have defined a custom arrow head since the default one is so small.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset{
    myarrow/.style={
        decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=2]{>}}},
        postaction={decorate},
        >=stealth
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [rectangle, fill=none, draw=black, text centered, inner sep=1em] 
        (box) 
        at (0, 0) 
        {box};
    \node [rectangle, fill=none, draw=black, text centered, inner sep=1em] 
        (second box) 
        at (3, 0) 
        {second box};

    % this works
    \draw [myarrow] (box.east) -- (second box.west);

    % but this doesn't
    \draw (box.north west)
        edge[myarrow, out = 120, in = 60, min distance = 3em]
        node [anchor = south] {feedback}
        (box.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The arrow head on the loop does not appear while the arrow head on the straight line does. Why is that? The box with the loop should look something like this (bad photoshop):

[image]

Using the default (tiny) arrow heads works:

[image]

Is the definition of `myarrow` wrong?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: If I use `at position .999` the arrow head shows.

Comment: That solves it, thanks! Any idea why `at position 1` doesn't work?

Comment: TeX isn't very good at maths ;). That is, it is not very *accurate*. So maybe `1` may become `1.something` i.e. not on the line at all... ?

Comment: @egreg Would you mind turning your comment and the explanation of cfr into an answer such that this question is no longer shown as unanswered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably a rounding error. If I use `at position 0.999` the arrowhead shows.

However, using this for straight arrows may be less than optimal, so I define also a `myarrowstraight` style for comparison.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset{
    myarrow/.style={
        decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.999 with {\arrow[scale=2]{>}}},
        postaction={decorate},
        >=stealth
    },
    myarrowstraight/.style={
        decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=2]{>}}},
        postaction={decorate},
        >=stealth
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [rectangle, fill=none, draw=black, text centered, inner sep=1em] 
        (box) 
        at (0, 0) 
        {box};
    \node [rectangle, fill=none, draw=black, text centered, inner sep=1em] 
        (second box) 
        at (3, 0) 
        {second box};

    % this works
    \draw [myarrow] (box.east) -- (second box.west);

    \draw [myarrowstraight] (box.north east) -- (second box.north west);

    % but this doesn't
    \draw (box.north west)
        edge[myarrow, out = 120, in = 60, min distance = 3em]
        node [anchor = south] {feedback}
        (box.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The `north east` to `north west` arrow uses the `myarrowstraight` style, a small offset of the arrowheads can perhaps be noticed.

[image]

Comment: I think it will be better to not repeat twice the style and do it like this : `myarrow/.style={... at position #1 with ...}; myarrow/.dafault={1};` and `mycurvedarrow/.style={myarrow=.999};`. Just a personal taste ;)

Comment: @Kpym Certainly so!