# Tikz, loop not appearing

Tags: tikz-pgf

> Why do i not get a loop at the middle up node in the following graph?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (1) at (0,0) ;
    \coordinate (2) at (0,-1);
    \coordinate (3) at (-1,0);
    \coordinate (4) at (-1,-1);
    \coordinate (5) at (1,0);
    \coordinate (6) at (1,-1);

    % ============================================
    % loop here:
    \draw (1) to[out=40,in=140,looseness=8] (1) ;
    % ============================================
    \draw (1) to[out=150,in=30] (3) ;
    \draw (1) to[out=210,in=-30] (3) ;
    \draw (5) to[out=150,in=30] (1) ;
    \draw (5) to[out=210,in=-30] (1) ;

    \draw (3) -- (4) ;
    \draw (1) -- (2) ;
    \draw (5) -- (6) ;
    \draw (4) -- (2) ;
    \draw (2) -- (6) ;
    \foreach \x in {(1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6)}{
        \fill \x circle[radius=2pt];
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

I tried to add a coordinate (1p) slight different then (1) as in [Tikz arrows on loops not showing up](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215199) ; but it does not work. I already noticed differences between node and coordinate; maybe this is also connected to a different behavior.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (1) at (0,0) ;
    \coordinate (1p) at (0,0.1) ;
    \coordinate (2) at (0,-1);
    \coordinate (3) at (-1,0);
    \coordinate (4) at (-1,-1);
    \coordinate (5) at (1,0);
    \coordinate (6) at (1,-1);

    \draw (1) to[out=150,in=30] (3) ;
    \draw (1) to[out=210,in=-30] (3) ;
    \draw (5) to[out=150,in=30] (1) ;
    \draw (5) to[out=210,in=-30] (1) ;
    \draw (1) to[out=40,in=140,looseness=8] (1p) ;

    \draw (3) -- (4) ;
    \draw (1) -- (2) ;
    \draw (5) -- (6) ;
    \draw (4) -- (2) ;
    \draw (2) -- (6) ;
    \foreach \x in {(1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6)}{
        \fill \x circle[radius=2pt];
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Orrible!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `loop` option to `draw`.

```
\draw (1) to[out=40,in=140,looseness=8,loop] (1) ;
```

[image]

Comment: oh my god! I tried it, BUT if you put it in front of looseness it does not work, incredible.

Comment: You are right, and looseness parameter is suppressing by loop. Changing it's values are not affecting the loop shape.

Answer (score 5):

This is an extended comment. The `looseness` key requires the start and end point of the loop to differ in order to be appreciated. So if one replaces your point coordinate by a node with some nontrivial dimensions, the `looseness` key works as expected.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {3,4,...,32,31,30,...,4}
{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path[use as bounding box] (-1.1,-1.1) rectangle (1.1,1.2);
    \coordinate (1) at (0,0)  ;
    \coordinate (2) at (0,-1);
    \coordinate (3) at (-1,0);
    \coordinate (4) at (-1,-1);
    \coordinate (5) at (1,0);
    \coordinate (6) at (1,-1);

    % ============================================
    % loop here:
    \node[inner sep=2pt] (aux) at (1) {}edge[out=60,in=120,loop,looseness=\X] (aux);
    %\draw (1) edge[out=40,in=140,loop,looseness=12] (1);
    % ============================================
    \draw (1) to[out=150,in=30] (3) ;
    \draw (1) to[out=210,in=-30] (3) ;
    \draw (5) to[out=150,in=30] (1) ;
    \draw (5) to[out=210,in=-30] (1) ;

    \draw (3) -- (4) ;
    \draw (1) -- (2) ;
    \draw (5) -- (6) ;
    \draw (4) -- (2) ;
    \draw (2) -- (6) ;
    \foreach \x in {(1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6)}{
        \fill \x circle[radius=2pt];
    }
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So the overall recommendation is to make the nodes extended objects, which also helps to shorten the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=2pt},nodes=bullet]
    \draw (0,0) node (1){} --(0,-1) node (2){} 
    (-1,0) node (3){} -- (-1,-1) node (4){} 
    (1,0) node (5){} -- (1,-1) node (6){} 
    (1)  edge[out=150,in=30] (3) (3)  edge[out=-30,in=-150] (1)
    (1)  edge[out=-30,in=-150] (5) (5)  edge[out=150,in=30] (1)
    (2) -- (4) -- (6)
    (1) to[out=40,in=140,looseness=18] (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for extended comment, +1.

Comment: thank you. I've to revise all my graphs. fortunately are still less than 10

Comment: about your last example: you do not specify the radius of the circle. what is the default? how to I specify it in the head: the two most intuitive (to me) variants  do not work

Comment: @PeptideChain Sorry, I do not understand your comment. The size of the bullet is controlled by `inner sep=2pt`.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I open a new question and post the link here

Comment: I've posted the new question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497948